# CakePHP-2.0, how can i upload an image for user profile?

Tags: php, cakephp, upload, cakephp-2.0, cakedc

I have used CakeDC users plugin.
I need to upload/add a profile picture for an user.

How can i do this?

Can anyone post the code to have upload image?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

I added this but i got only a button.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Document', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
echo $this->Form->file('Document.submittedfile');
echo $this->Form-end();
```

How can i set/get the path of uploaded file?

Comment: What is your **specific** question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I updated the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter the framework you use, this will works to PHP.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

PD: I suggest that next time, try to be more specific in your questions.

Comment: Two things: 1) http://w3fools.com 2) Posting links to tutorials is not answering a question. If that link goes down, your answer is now utterly useless. Please copy over relevant information from the pages to which you link.

Comment: I put the link, not the contents, because that page contains much information that I think may be of interest to @prime

Comment: Furthermore @MetalFrog, the question is too general (although everyone deserves this one) and a specific response would be very extensive. Also, if you do not like w3schools.com not have to dislike others. With all this I mean that your comment is somewhat unfortunate.

Comment: In that case, you should reply with a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @MetalFrog At that point I agree with you ;)